# Use docker buildx feature with Jenkins docker.build

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-build

I want to use experimental docker [buildx](https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/) feature with my Jenkins pipeline [docker.build](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/).
AFAIK docker.build allows only *build arguments* provide. But want I need is provide *build* as argument itself provide to *buildx*

Answer (score -1):

You can set alias for `docker buildx` by running this command `docker buildx install`.

This will use `buildx` builder whenever you call `docker build`.

[Source](https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/#set-buildx-as-the-default-builder)

However, Jenkins' docker plugin doesn't support it at the time of writing and there is an [open issue for that](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-61372).

Alternatively, you can build images without plugin:

```
steps {
  script {
    sh """
      docker build buildx ...
    """
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you replaced arguments positions. Assuming you meant `docker buildx build ...`